# How to read XML Child Node Value in a String using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a String which gets its value dynamically from other server. Value of string is

```
$xmloutput = '<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/getRecordById">
    <result>
        <Leads>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="LEADID">131</FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">20001</FL>
                <FL val="Lead Owner"><![CDATA[Aaron]]></FL>
                <FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Carol]]></FL>
                <FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Custer]]></FL>
                <FL val="Email"><![CDATA[good51@gmail.com]]></FL>
            </row>
            <row no="2">
                <FL val="LEADID">2070</FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">20001</FL>
                <FL val="Lead Owner"><![CDATA[Aaron]]></FL>
                <FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Florence, SC]]></FL>
            </row>
        </Leads>
    </result>
</response>
```

My Question is, generally we use `$xml = simplexml_load_file("test1.xml");` to load XML files, but here in my requirement it is a String, how can i read this String value and extract the child node and its value? Example:

```
<FL val="LEADID">131</FL> // its key is LEADID and value is 131
<FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Carol]]></FL> // its key is First Name and value is Carol
```

Is there a way to put this into Array? so that its easy for me to print out its node value?

Comment: Use [simplexml_load_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) instead if you have the xml as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) that is for reading xml from string. Then loop through `row` elements and in loop, loop through `FL` elements and then get text content and attribute of element.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
foreach ($xml->Leads->row as $row) {
    foreach ($row->FL as $fl) {
        echo "{$fl} => {$fl['val']}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting following Warning Message for the this line `foreach ($xml->Leads->row as $row) `
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\zohoclient\xmlToHtml.php on line 50

Comment: @A.T.M.Hasan It's warning and you can turn off it using `error_reporting(0)`

Comment: It is not giving me the output at the same time!

Comment: @Mohammad It's not a warning you should turn off. It means the thing you're trying to loop over isn't actually an array, which means you have a bug in the code.

Comment: @Barmar The xml that is in question is invalid. I removed `response ` tag from it. May cause of error is it

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy! `foreach ($xml->result->Leads->row as $row)` worked for me.